# Getting data speed of wifi/mobile network programmatically

Tags: android, networking, mobile, android-wifi

How do I get the data speed of wifi/mobile network programmatically in my application.

Comment: Try opening a socket and download some bytes from somewhere (say 256kb) and measure how long it takes for the download to complete

Comment: So what did you find? I want to check internet speed and set image or video url accordingly for example if internet speed is between `50kbps - 150 kbps`  **link1** , `150kbps -  500kbps`  **link2** and  `>500kbps` **link3**. so How to achieve that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the code for getting the WiFi speed:

```java
WifiManager wifiManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo != null) {
    Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
}
```

For mobile network speed, refer to the below link:

http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=47

Comment: Perhaps it gives the maximum speed....

Comment: None-static method 'getSystemService'
 please help me fix this issue
@Mansuu....

Comment: pass a reference of Context whereever you have written this method to get wifi speed